# Is there a way to make calculateRoute function take into account the waypoint radius?

Tags: here-api

When using `calculate route` api with `!geo` waypoints with radius https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html i expect the routing algorithm to find a route (fastest, as defined in parameters) that passes through the **surroundings** of the waypoint.

Unfortunately, the radius is ignored, and the routing algorithm returns a route that passes precisely through the point - which can be ie. on the other side of the road. This causes a lot of unnecessary u-turns and makes the output unusable. Are the radius units meters, how to make the radius work as expected?

See sample request below:
`/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=*****&app_code=*********&waypoint0=geo!52.59056113201988,13.400831222534181&waypoint1=geo!52.617119794673464,13.387699127197267,500&waypoint2=geo!52.63954788026919,13.364953994750978,500&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&alternatives=0&departure=2019-12-11T05:31:08.633Z&routeAttributes=shape`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comma it should be semicolon before the radius, so:

```
... waypoint1=geo!52.617119794673464,13.387699127197267;500& ...
```

Comment: Didn't notice the difference on the examples. Thank you.